# Excel VBA / Run time Error 458

Tags: json, excel, vba

In excel VBA, i get :

> Run time error 458 : Variable uses an Automation type not supported in
>   Visual Basic

I get this error on the last line of my code below.

I'm using JsonConverter module to parse this simple JSon string:
{"ok":true,"result":[]}

I've added the parsed JSon string to the Watch window, see attached image for the type of variable that it returns. Any clue ?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8sXK.jpg)

```
With objRequest
      .Open "GET", strGetData, False
      .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      .send (strPostData)
       GetSessionId = .responseText
       'MsgBox GetSessionId
       Workbooks("Telegram test.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1").Cells(7, "G") = GetSessionId
       Set ParsedTelegramIn = JsonConverter.ParseJson(GetSessionId)
       MsgBox ParsedTelegramIn("ok")
```

Comment: You may have to add the square brackets to your JSON string, or add a json "root". See if they are missing. If not, post the json if possible, I had a similar issue.

Comment: Are you on Mac or Windows?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your feed-back. My original Json string was: {"ok":true,"result":[]}.     Now, I've added brackets and the error message changes to Run-time error 5 - Invalid Procedure call or argument.

Comment: The system does not seem to pick up the "ok" and "result" arguments. I can only call ParsedTelegramIn(1). I cannot call ParsedTelegramIn("ok").

Comment: If i check the Json string at https://jsonlint.com/, it says it's valid. With or without brackets.

Comment: I'm on windows.